# Partial (specific releases) mirror of Ubuntu Archive via rsync only

Tags: apt, rsync, localrepository

I'm looking to build a Ubuntu repository archive for both i386/x64 architectures on 12.04 (precise).  This is to bring in to a facility where I am working with no Internet connection.

Circumstances limit my ability to do this from a full Linux machine - I just have the `rsync` tool available and a 1TB external hard drive.  `debmirror` is not a viable option.

I can run

```
 rsync -a --progress rsync://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ /volumeUSB1/usbshare/mirror/ubuntu
```

and while this accomplishes what I need, it does so for *every* release that is still supported.  I only need packages related to 12.04 (precise).

Is there an easy way to modify the rsync command so that I get only the repositories that I need from 12.04 while keeping in place all the structure I need for the mirror to work once connected back to the Ubuntu machine?

---

Bonus points for multiple commands that I could execute in parallel to (hopefully) speed up the download process.

Answer (score 1):

if you can install anything on the machine you are USING to transfer, try dpkg-repack, it will put all of the applications into .deb files that you can install on site on any debian based system

on the transfer machine, run these commands

$ sudo apt-get install dpkg-repack fakeroot
$ mkdir ~/dpkg-repack; cd ~/dpkg-repack
$ fakeroot -u dpkg-repack `dpkg --get-selections | grep install | cut -f1

then on the target machine(s) run this

sudo dpkg -i *.deb

Comment: The box I am doing the download from is a Synology NAS.  I don't have specific packages to install, but rather want to have the whole universe available for many machines on the isolated network

Comment: even on a one tb drive, I don't know how much of it will fit

Comment: That's a valid point; I have found references that "the Ubuntu Archive takes up about 680 GB of space." (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Rsyncmirror)  Not sure if that includes all of the available releases.

Comment: or dependencies, along with the fact that not all installs ONLY require the ubuntu repository

Comment: Also true; I plan on having to bring in some additional things, but would like to have as many of the core packages already there.

Comment: don't know how you would mirror that, it might just be better to get the package files instead of mirroring the repository in its own right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15396/discussion-between-cslstr-and-sbergeron).